# caffe:Check failed: target_blobs.size() == source_layer.blobs_size() (2 vs. 1) Incompatible number of blobs for layer conv1

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, convolution, pycaffe

I modify the FCN net and design a new net,in which I use two ImageData Layer as input param and hope the net produces a picture as output.
here is the [train_val.prototxt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24520856/) and the [deploy.prototxt](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24520862/)

the original picture and the label are both gray scale pics and sizes are 224*224.
I've trained a caffemodel and use infer.py to use the caffemodel to do a segmentation,but meet the error:

```
 F0505 06:15:08.072602 30713 net.cpp:767] Check failed: target_blobs.size() == source_layer.blobs_size() (2 vs. 1) Incompatible number of blobs for layer conv1
```

here is the infer.py file:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
caffe_root = '/home/zhaimo/' 
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, caffe_root + 'caffe-master/python')

import caffe
im = Image.open('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/data/vessel/test/13.png')
in_ = np.array(im, dtype=np.float32)
#in_ = in_[:,:,::-1]
#in_ -= np.array((104.00698793,116.66876762,122.67891434))
#in_ = in_.transpose((2,0,1))


net = caffe.Net('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/deploy.prototxt', '/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/snapshot/train/_iter_200000.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1, *in_.shape)
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = in_
net.forward()
out = net.blobs['score'].data[0].argmax(axis=0)

plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('/home/zhaimo/fcn-master/mo/result/13.png')
```

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your bias term in `conv1`. In your `train.prototxt` it is set to false. But in your `deploy.prototxt` it is not and by default that is true. That is why weight loader is looking for two blobs.

Comment: here is another error:`F0508 03:20:57.777287 22515 base_conv_layer.cpp:189] Check failed: bottom[0]->num_axes() == first_spatial_axis + num_spatial_axes_ (3 vs. 4) bottom num_axes may not change. `   I guess it is because the dim in input_param should be 1,1,224,224,so I change it but meet another error:`Cannot copy param 0 weights from layer 'conv1'; shape mismatch.  Source param shape is 64 3 7 7 (9408); target param shape is 64 1 7 7 (3136). To learn this layer's parameters from scratch rather than copying from a saved net, rename the layer` how to solve this problem,please?

Comment: btw I'm sure my train and test data are both 8bit gray scale pics.

Comment: This 2nd issue is with the number of channels (`rgb vs gray`). Your train and test both should have same number of channels. So do appropriate conversion based on your need.

Comment: thanks a lot.I changed the deploy.prototxt and trainval.prototxt,but still can not solve the first error.I still can not figure out the problem because all pics' channels are the same.